# .NET 6 : got error when try to get the child of app.setting

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0

I'm using the code below to get the value of the URL

```
var x = _config.GetSection("appsettings:AuthToken:Endpoint").Value;
```

This is my `app.setting`:

```
"AuthToken": {
    "Endpoint": "https://api.develope.com/users/guest-create",
    "Username": "admin@example.com",
    "Password": "password",
    "RedirectUrl": "localhost:8080",
    "GrantType": "password"
}
```

I always got the error

> System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

because of Null

Answer (score 0):

No need to add the "appsettings".
It should be like this:

```
var x = _config.GetSection("AuthToken:Endpoint").Value;
```

Comment: I already did that and still got exception error  var x = _config.GetSection("AuthToken:Endpoint").Value;

Comment: Can you provide the full stack trace (Or your startup code) ?
We need to know which object was null.
Did you build the configuration?

Answer (score 0):

> But the application does not get the variable from Windows. How can I
> get it?

Actually, based on the scenario it can be extracted from program.cs file and from the controller level as well.

Let's have a look in practice how we can get it based on either environment.

Program.cs:

Way:1

```cs
var getEndpoint = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("AuthToken:Endpoint");
```

Way:2

```cs
var configuration = new ConfigurationBuilder().AddJsonFile("appsettings.json").Build();
var way_2_getEndpoint = configuration.GetValue<string>("AuthToken:Endpoint");
```

[image]

**Note:** Following the same way, you can get the endpoint or any other property as well.

Controller Level:

```cs
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
    private readonly IConfiguration _appSettingsValue;
    private string endpointURL;

    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _appSettingsValue = configuration;
        endpointURL = _appSettingsValue["AuthToken:Endpoint"]!;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var getAppSettingsValue = endpointURL;
        return View();
    }

}
```

[image]

Output:

[image]

**Note:** You can [refer to this sample](https://github.com/kironiitdu/ExtractAppSettingsValue). If you would like to know more details on [configuration providers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#application-configuration-providers) you could [check our official document here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#application-configuration-providers).